# Swipe action not working

Tags: android, swipe

Based on an online tutorial, I've set up a swipe detection action that works in one project but is completely innocuous in another project. Why is that? For the latter, there is no error on eclipse, upon launching, there is nothing on log cat and there is nothing to indicate that its selected at all.

The xml side is just a simple text view, but on the java back end is as follows.

```
   public class Swipesample extends Activity {
float x1,x2;
float y1, y2;
   }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) 
    {

                 switch (touchevent.getAction())
                 {
                        // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                         {
                             x1 = touchevent.getX();
                             y1 = touchevent.getY();
                             break;
                        }
                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                         {
                             x2 = touchevent.getX();
                             y2 = touchevent.getY(); 

                             //if left to right sweep event on screen
                             if (x1 < x2) 
                             {
                                 Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                              }

                             // if right to left sweep event on screen
                             if (x1 > x2)
                             {
                                 Toast.makeText(this, "Right to Left Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             }

                             // if UP to Down sweep event on screen
                             if (y1 < y2) 
                             {
                                 Toast.makeText(this, "UP to Down Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             }

                             //if Down to UP sweep event on screen
                             if (y1 > y2)
                             {
                                 Toast.makeText(this, "Down to UP Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                              }
                             break;
                         }
                 }
                 return false;
    }     
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

return true,please.if return false,the Motion Event will not dispatch to your view any more.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've tried it, but it doesn't work. Still no response at all.

Comment: As far as swipe goes, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same tut, after modifying it in the following way, it works like a charm.

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    int eventaction = e.getAction();
        switch (eventaction) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            x1 = e.getX();
            y1 = e.getY();
        break;
        }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getY();
        //if left to right sweep event on screen
        if (x1 > x2+300){
        // Todo whatever you want to be done
        }
        // if right to left sweep event on screen
        if (x1+300 < x2){
        // Todo whatever you want to be done
        }
        // if UP to Down sweep event on screen
        if (y1 > y2+300){
        // Todo whatever you want to be done
        }
        //if Down to UP sweep event on screen
        if (y1+300 < y2){
        // Todo whatever you want to be done
        }
        break;
        }
        }
    return false;
    }
```

You might notice I've added 300 on the comparisons between x1,x2 and y1,y2. Thats only there to allow for some tolerance on the vertical/horizontal swipe, else I found it to be too sensitive.
Hope it helps ;o)